# current location of caller. or

Tags: iphone

can i get current location of caller. or receiver.

If i call my friend. with some number example: 89303894340[mobile number].  Do i get his location latitude longitude values.

Comment: Even if you could, they won't always agree to provide it.

Answer (score 3):

No. This isn't currently possible, and I'd personally be surprised if was anytime soon. (It's the telecoms networks that would control such things.)